# How to know which bash commands are avalaible for me?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I'm using a webshell on some sites, and I want to know which bash commands are available outside `/home/myname`. How to know which commands are avalaible for an ordinary user (non sudo)?

Comment: are you looking for something like    compgen -b   ??

Comment: no , the one like cat, ls, etc
https://ss64.com/bash/

Comment: compgen -c   ?? Try this, it should work

Comment: I guess you could split your path on colons and run a `find` on each with `-maxdepth 1` and appropoate filtration of *"executableness"*...

Comment: @abhishekphukan this doesnt answer my question , some commands yields "Permission denied", because of non sudoers. I want to know which command is available